# How to secure sqlite db using password in java application

Tags: java, sqlite

I am using SQLite JDBC driver from xerial project.

Can i secure my sqlite db using username & password with java? If yes, how?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1807320/username-in-sqlite3

Comment: no idea @Md. Minhaz Nihal, but a quick search guide me to encryption read this https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/63343/encrypting-data-within-sqlite-database-in-java-how-to-store-key and https://developer.blackberry.com/bbos/java/documentation/sqlite_security_1981753_11.html

Answer (score 1):

I do not know, is this answer necessary for you now? But hope this answer can help other people, who have faced kind of similar problems.

- First of all, The base SQLite engine doesn't have any password/encryption options. So you can not set a username and password.
- As base SQLite does not include an encryption option. That is available as a paid option (SEE) from the suppliers of SQLite, or there are other 3rd party options available.
- For JDBC especially, you can follow this [github repository](https://github.com/Willena/sqlite-jdbc-crypt). Here you find the way around to secure your SQLite DB. In their Readme file, you will find this code-block, how they create their DB Connection string. But before this, you have to configure encryption mode.

```
//Using the SQLiteMC default parameters
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:file:file.db", new SQLiteMCConfig().withKey("Key").toProperties());
Connection connection = new SQLiteMCConfig().withKey("Key").createConnection("jdbc:sqlite:file:file.db");

//Using Chacha20
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:file:file.db", SQLiteMCChacha20Config.getDefault().withKey("Key").toProperties());
Connection connection = SQLiteMCChacha20Config.getDefault().withKey("Key").createConnection("jdbc:sqlite:file:file.db");
```

- As you use JDBC, that means your application is java based, in that case, H2 DB will well suit your application. It has strong security [features](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html).